# C# rdlc for a single object, no table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I'm trying to make an rdlc report in Visual Studio 2015 for a single instance of an object. It seems as though I always have to pass in an enumerable list as the datasource, and it always has a table.

Is it possible to just pass in a single object and not have a table? I want to have a background image and use text boxes to display the data that I want to display.

Thank you for any responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this.

1. If it's just a single item, why not just use a parameter? Just pass your single value via a parameter.
2. If you want to go the data source route, yes, you have pass in an enumerable, but that is as easy as this:
   `var data = new string[] { "my value"}`
   and using the `First` function:
   `=First(Fields!ProductNumber.Value, "Category")`

Either way, you can still use textboxes.

Comment: I used the method of adding a list with only one item (my object). I didn't want my table to be shown, so I just hid the table by setting it to not visible.